# Large twitter list look up

Tags: twitter

How can I search keywords from a large list of users? I’ve looked at the documentation, but there appears to be limits.

I will have a list of maybe 20,000 users. And, I would like to know when anyone of them tweet about certain keywords.

It looks like the List tweet lookup function is limited to the previous 800 tweets.

Lists appear to have a limit of 5000 accounts. I could get around that by creating a few lists.

I want to search the list about once a day.

Any help would be appreciated!